# Why does my fourier transformed gaussianlike function, does not look like a gaussian in fourierspace?

Tags: python, numpy, fft, numpy-ndarray

I have got the following function , the central peak is approximately gaussianlike.[image]  I used the numpy library for the FFT algorithm `from numpy.fft import fft as fourier, ifft as ifourier` and transformed my function into fourierspace`func_fourier = fourier(func)`, I expected a gaussianlike function in fourier space aswell, but I got this result, while plotting `plt.plot(np.abs(func_fourier)), since I dont know what x-values to plot over in fourierspace. Since I do not have information on the frequency spacing.`:[image]
Any tips or ideas what the reason might be or how to interpret this result from numpy.fft() ?

Comment: You could verify your hypothesis by subtracting 0.2 before doing the Fourier transform.

Comment: ye I tried that but it does not do anything, the reason being that a continuum level in inverse fourier space is just a delta function in fourier space. I also tried transforming a standard gaussian, and it kind off gives the same result. So I probably am asking how to interpret the result of the fft algorithm.

Comment: For the plot in fourierspace I just use: plt.plot(func_fourier). Because I am not sure what x-values to plot over in fourierspace.

Comment: What does your function look like outside the 400-2000 x range you show in your plot? Or is it only defined for these values?

Comment: yes its only defined on these values I plotted

Comment: You are confusing the DFT and the FT. You are using the FFT, which computes a DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform). You are thinking in terms of the (continuous-domain) Fourier Transform, which does not do the same thing. For one, the DFT uses as origin both in time and frequency domains is the first array element. This means that your 'delta function' is an increase of the first bin (0 frequency component). It also means that your Gaussian function is centered around that first bin, and wraps around to the end. Look into using `fftshift`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cris Luengo mentioned in his comment you want to use np.fft.fftshift() to shift the zero frequency. So using`func_fourier = np.fft.fftshift(fourier(func))` and plotting `plt.plot(np.abs(func_fourier))` you receive the expected gaussianlike transform:[image]